# Updating fields by using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to get an object from the database and update one field by using sequels. I haven't found the update method in the documentation. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.update({
  updatedAt: null,
}, {
  where: {
    deletedAt: {
      $ne: null
    }
  }
});
```

From [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#where).